# Sublime Text 3 wont compile python, but terminal will

Tags: python, django, terminal

I can get the code to build when running from the terminal, but not from sublime text 3. I guess I need to tell sublime that Django exist somehow? How do I do this?

Thanks

```
from django.db import models
ImportError: No module named 'django'
```

Comment: i think you have multiple versions of python installed . if that's right then that explain a lot , confirm is that right  so i could give answer

Comment: Hi, thanks for reply. Yes, I have both python 2 and 3 installed

Comment: then your python version that sublime use does not have Django installed , check sublime -PYTHONPATH- and keep us updated